# Painting based on array of values

Tags: java, swing

I want to paint rivers based on information stored in a 2D array. Every index has information whether it has water or not (isDry()). How would I go about optimizing my current code?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    for(int i = 0; i<array2d.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j<array2d[0].length; j++) {
            if(!(array2d[i][j].isDry())){
                paintPixel(Graphics2D g2, i, j);
            }
         }
      }
public void paintPixel(Graphics2D g2, int x, int y) {
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.drawLine(x, y, x, y);

}
```

Comment: Code optimization is that way: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

If the values returned from `isDry` don't change regularly, then you can pre-filter the dry areas. For example, just use the `java.awt.Point` class to represent only the points which you should paint. Add them in an `ArrayList` and iterate it every time you paint.

Even better probably would be, if the values don't change regularly, you can pre-draw all the points in a `BufferedImage` and draw the image instead of iterating through the `ArrayList`. But that would probably depend on the size of the image too. For example, could drawing an image 1920x1080 be less efficient than drawing 10 points? I guess it could.

So the answer here, to my knowledge, would be: it depends on the lifetime of the values returned by `isDry` and the multitude of the non-dry areas.